# Get custom post type slug for an archive page

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, custom-post-type-archives

How do I discover the custom post type slug when I'm on an archive page?

For instance if `/products/` fires the `archive-products.php` template, how (pragmatically) do I get the post type slug?

Thanks

Answer (score 23):

To get the current post type use `get_post_type()`. Then ask `get_post_type_object()` for all the data you need, for example the slug:

```
$post_type = get_post_type();
if ( $post_type )
{
    $post_type_data = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
    $post_type_slug = $post_type_data->rewrite['slug'];
    echo $post_type_slug;
}
```

Comment: I think (hadn't tested) [`get_queried_object()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_queried_object/) would get to same info in less moves.

Comment: @Rarst Maybe, but I think the code I suggested is easier to understand.

Comment: Toscho's solutions is wrong, because get_post_type returns the post type of current page, and, when you are into archive page, this function alwasy return "page". I'm sarching to solve the same: When I am into archive page of 'books' (4 example), I want this: 'books'. When I get it I'll post it.

Comment: unfortunately it's not that simple, though you'd be better off with just `$posttype = get_query_var('post_type');` ... I've added a comprehensive alternative.

Comment: I don think This is answer cover the whole story. You should check the install rewrite rules as many filters (like woocommerce shop page) is making changes. **Use the Worpdress own mecanism instead**, see my answer somewhere below.

Answer (score 7):

I'm using this outside of the loop on the archive.php template to get which custom post archive I'm on.

It's a combo of the methods that both @toscho and @Rarst recommended:

```
$post_type = get_queried_object();
echo $post_type->rewrite['slug'];
```

Update: @majick pointed out that this only works if you've set the rewrite slug for your CPT. Rewrite slug is optional when registering a CPT and defaults to post_type if not set.

Comment: when I tried this I got `Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$rewrite in ***\wp-content\themes\marks-remarks\archive.php on line 4`

Comment: this will only work if the rewrite slug is set for the registered CPT, as it is optional and defaults to the post_type

Comment: Thanks for catching that @majick! I've updated the post to reflect your info.

Comment: turns out that was the tip of the iceberg... check my new answer for the underwater part :-)

Answer (score 6):

The answers get confusing. And maybe Im as well but the **headline** question is:

> Get custom post type *slug* for an **archive page**

If you mean **post type archive** landing-page, and when `is_post_type_archive()` returns `true`, you want the slug that responing to **current** viewing archive:

```
/* returns /products/ */

$responding_name = str_replace(get_home_url(), '', get_post_type_archive_link(get_query_var('post_type')));

/* continue to get 'products' without slug slashes */
$responding_name = str_replace('/', '', $responding_name);
```

-- END OF ANSWERING THE QUESTION --

**Explanation:**

You cant rely on the *registered slug*. Wordpress is not either. For example, when calling `get_post_type_archive_link()` Wordpress is checking the **current rewrite rules** for your **install** .

Wherever you are, inside or outside loop, current archive or single post, **reverse** the `get_post_type_archive_link()` mechanism. (Permalinks enabled.)

**Considerations:**

As mentioned here, the post type(s) in **current query** can be an `array`. You can go futher with **your intensions** with filter out the post type you look for, example:

```
$post_type = get_query_var('post_type'); 
if(is_array($post_type)) $post_type = reset($post_type);
```

or

```
if(isset($post_types[0])) $post_type = $post_types[0];
```

**Another point of view:**

Woocommerce example, is registered with 'products' post type object but in reality uses rewritten rule name (shop):

```
/* returns shop */
$responding_name = str_replace('/', '', str_replace(get_home_url(), '', get_post_type_archive_link('product')));
```

> Mark, Im using `$responding_name`, because the objectives might vary.
>   A post archive does not exists, its just a url.

Comment: This made it very clear thank you. Was looking for this solution. If the question was not looking for "only just the post type name", this should be a woted up answer.

Comment: Yes! `$post_type_link = get_post_type_archive_link( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) );` was all I needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code and this  code is working for me,

```
 $t_slug = get_query_var('term');
```

Comment: This is better than `get_post_type()`, as this will return the correct value even when the archive is empty

Answer (score 2):

t should be noted that if `has_archive` is set to true while registering the Custom Post Type, the post type archive `/cptslug/` will be internally rewritten to `?post_type=cptslug`. So this would also mean `is_post_type_archive()` will return true.

Unfortunately, where the registered rewrite slug is *different* to the post type, you are not actually reliably getting the `post_type`. eg. if your post type was `myplugin_cars` and your rewrite slug was `cars` and you need to be getting `myplugin_cars` then even this (to prevent errors if the current queried object is *not* a custom post type) will still fail:

```
$queryobject = get_queried_object();
if (has_property('rewrite',$queryobject)) {
    if (isset($queryobject->rewrite['slug'])) {
         $posttype = $queryobject->rewrite['slug'];
     }
 }
```

But because `is_post_type_archive` is true this is more reliable:

```
if (is_post_type_archive()) {
    $posttype = get_query_var('post_type');
    // which is basically the same as:
    // global $wp_query;
    // $posttype = $wp_query->query_vars['post_type'];
} 
else ($posttype = 'post';}
```

But hang on, there's more... turns out with a little testing it really isn't that simple either... what if you are on a taxonomy archive page with multiple post types in the taxonomy..? Or assign post tags to a custom post type other than post? Or are on an author archive page? Date archive page? ...or even have a complex `tax_query` or `meta_query` for `WP_Query`?

The only reliable answer (without testing for every possible archive case) is to loop the actual posts in the query... Here is the full function I came up with to work on both singular and archive pages, and allowing you to optionally pass a custom query object (or post object/post ID for singular posts):

```
function get_current_post_types($object=null) {

    // if a numeric value passed, assume it is a post ID
    if ( ($object) && (is_numeric($object)) ) {$object = get_post($object);}
    // if an object is passed, assume to be a post object
    if ( ($object) && (is_object($object)) ) {return get_post_type($object);}

    // standard single post type checks
    if (is_404()) {return '';}
    // update: removed this check, handled by is_singular
    // if (is_single()) {return 'post';}
    if (is_page()) {return 'page';}
    if (is_attachment()) {return 'attachment';}
    if (is_singular()) {return get_post_type();}

    // if a custom query object was not passed, use $wp_query global
    if ( (!$object) || (!is_object($object)) ) {
        global $wp_query; $object = $wp_query;
    }
    if (!is_object($object)) {return '';} // should not fail

    // if the post_type query var has been explicitly set
    // (or implicitly set on the cpt via a has_archive redirect)
    // ie. this is true for is_post_type_archive at least
    // $vqueriedposttype = get_query_var('post_type'); // $wp_query only
    if (property_exists($object,'query_vars')) {
        $posttype = $object->query_vars['post_type'];
        if ($posttype) {return $posttype;}
    }

    // handle all other cases by looping posts in query object
    $posttypes = array();
    if (method_exists($object,'found_posts')) {
        if ($object->found_posts > 0) {
            $queriedposts = $object->posts;
            foreach ($queriedposts as $queriedpost) {
                $posttype = $queriedpost->post_type;
                if (!in_array($posttype,$posttypes)) {$posttypes[] = $posttype;}
            }
            if (count($posttypes == 1)) {return $posttypes[0];}
            else {return $posttypes;}
         }
     }
     return ''; // nothin to see here
}
```

This will reliably (did I say that?) return an array of post types if more than one is present, or a string with the single post type if there is only one type.
All you need to do is:

```
$posttypes = get_current_post_types();
// or pass a post ID 
$posttypes = get_current_post_types($postid);
// or pass a post object
$posttypes = get_current_post_types($post);
// or pass a custom query - that has been run
$posttypes = get_current_post_types($query);
```

*Example Usage* (just for fun):

```
add_filter('the_posts','myplugin_fading_thumbnails',10,2);
function myplugin_fading_thumbnails($posts,$query) {
    if (!is_archive()) {return $posts;}
    $cptslug = 'myplugin_slug'; $dosomethingcool = false;
    $posttypes = get_current_post_types($query);
    if ( (is_array($posttypes)) && (in_array($cptslug,$posttypes)) ) {$dosomethingcool = true;}
    elseif ($cptslug == $posttypes) {$dosomethingcool = true;}

    if ($dosomethingcool) {
        global $fadingthumbnails; $fadingthumbnails = $cptslug;
        if (!has_action('wp_footer','myplugin_cpt_script')) {
            add_action('wp_footer','myplugin_cpt_script');
        }
    }

    function myplugin_cpt_script() {
        global $fadingthumbnails;
        echo "<script>var thumbnailclass = 'img.thumbtype-".$fadingthumbnails."';
        function fadeoutthumbnails() {jQuery(thumbnailclass).fadeOut(3000,fadeinthumbnails);}
        function fadeinthumbnails() {jQuery(thumbnailclass).fadeIn(3000,fadeoutthumbnails);}
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {fadeoutthumbnails();});
        </script>";
    }

    return $posts;
 }
```

To see the effect, change the custom post type in the code to `post`, and add a `thumbtype-post` class attribute to your post thumbnail images...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$posttype_slug = $queried_object->query_var;
echo $posttype_slug;
```

use $posttype_slug var whatever you need

Comment: it needs to `$queried_object->query_var['post_type'];` for this to work...

Comment: No.
$queried_object->query_var containe only string of post type. it's not object or array. look at this image: http://prntscr.com/bd58e1

Comment: ok but only if the queried object is *definitely* a custom post type object, you will get a different corresponding object and thus empty value for category/tax/tag/author archive pages for example. even for `?post_type=post` I get empty. compare with `get_query_var('post_type');`

Answer (score -4):

```
if( get_post_type( get_the_ID() ) == 'projects' )
{
  //enter code for this post type
}
```